# Codekit fails to refresh the browser after second edit?

Tags: css, mamp, codekit

I'm currently viewing Codekit's preview link of my page in the browser. After saving changes to my CSS, Codekit will auto-refresh the browser and render the changes as expected - **the first time only.**

After saving another change to the CSS, **Codekit fails to refresh the browser the second time**. I suspect this has to do with the structure of my files in conjunction with my external server (MAMP).

Currently I've specified my the following as External Server Address `http://localhost/`

And have set the following as my Preview Subpath: `/sw/?v=/car/create`

Could it be, that only files in the document root auto-refresh every time changes are made but not those in the **Preview Subpath**?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: I had a similar problem...my markup was incorrect because I was in a hurry to test it out.  Proper markup fixed my problem.

Answer (score 0):

I have weird CodeKit2 behavior too: any project autorefreshes fine when I put it to the `~/Desktop/myproject` but fails to reload when I put it to the `~/Dropbox/oluckyman-air/Projects/Work/myproject` folder.
Seems that length of the project path is affects the autoreload feature.
I had workaround this problem by moving my project to the `~/Projects/myproject` folder.

Update:
As Bryan Jones says it’s actually a bug in OS X. See here for a list of ways to work around it: http://feedback.livereload.com/knowledgebase/articles/86239-os-x-fsevents-bug-may-prevent-monitoring-of-certai